# Libraries disappeared overnight

Tags: python, libraries

Last night I was using matplotlib, pylab, and pandas. This morning none of them work and I can't figure out what happened. Is there a reason why all of my libraries would vanish?

Using OS X if that matters.

I'm new to programming, and I installed ipython and the packages I've been using, along with qtinstaller from a tutorial I found, but I'm lost. Is there an obvious solution to why the libraries could disappear, or an easy way to completely wipe all of my python apps and start over? I don't have my computer backed up so if I go that route I need a way to keep my files

Thanks, 
Josh

Comment: Did you change anything between the last time the libraries worked and now? And is your python path set correctly?

Comment: I'm guessing the Tooth Fairy finally got with the times. Is there a pile of money under your pillow?

Comment: My path is /usr/local/bin/python. I didn't every purposely change it. And I didn't change anything to my knowledge. I installed a package last night that was a collection of finance tools, but that's it.

No money under my pillow, unfortunately

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the `which` command to see if the path to Python has changed.

```
$ which python
/usr/bin/python
```

Most likely, your packages were installed in `usr/bin/python` and installing ipython changed it to something else.

Comment: I got: /usr/local/bin/python. I've been using ipython the whole time. I installed it before most of the packages.

Comment: I installed Anaconda for some Python libraries and it changed my PATH, causing my existing libraries to vanish, so that's the explanation I have. Do your finance tools libraries still load, if nothing else does?

Comment: No, it isn't here. I am looking at the module list but I'm not sure which ones came with python

Comment: Got it working, your anaconda comment helped me figure it out, thanks.